# How to use CSS3 transition callbacks with jQuery.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, css, transition

I am using the following snippet of jQuery code to perform an AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: page,
    context: $(pageContent),
    beforeSend: function(){
        $(pageContent).css('opacity', '0');
    },
    success: function(html){
        $(pageContent).html(html);
    },
    complete: function(){
        $(pageContent).css('opacity', '1');
    }
});
```

I also set up CSS3 transitions so that the change of opacity fades in and out during 0.25 second.
The desired result is that (after a click on a link) a section of the page fades out, then the content is replaced, and finally the section fades in again (showing the new content).

The issue is that the content is replaced by the Ajax answer before the fade-out transition finishes.

What would you do to get the AJAX request to launch only once the CSS3 transition has finished?

---

Reading through different threads got me considering this solution:

```
box.addEventListener( 
     'transitionEnd', 
     function( event ) { 
         alert( "Finished transition!" ); // here I could launch my Ajax request
     }, false );
```

I could use something like this to launch the ajax request only when the fade-out finishes, but:

- it involves dealing with the first transition outside of the $.ajax method (thus removing the beforeSend method)
- I don't know how to listen only at the opacity transitions
- It doesn't really makes sense to me that the ajax request is triggered by a transition, as it is currently triggered by a click on a link.

I also had a look at the jQuery animate function but it doesn't seem to use CSS3 transitions.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: +1 on the listening only to specific transitions taking place. That is important to understand, especially when using multiple transitions at once on the same element (i.e. 'box')

Comment: Also would be important to point out that this method outright breaks browsers that do not support transitions at all, whereas using JavaScript timers would still be able to control some of the experience.

Comment: Sounds like you don't actually need a fade out then. Otherwise... you're forcing the user to wait longer than they actually need to.

Answer (score -1):

If you're willing to ditch transitions for jquery animate:

```
$(pageContent).animate({'opacity': '0'},250,
   function(){
      $.ajax({
          url: page,
          context: $(pageContent),
          success: function(html){
              $(pageContent).html(html);
          },
          complete: function(){
              $(pageContent).animate({'opacity': '1'},250);
          }
      });
   });
```

Didn't test it, so if the syntax is slightly off, sorry.  Gives you the idea though.  The ajax call is made once the animate to 0 opacity finishes.

Comment: Yes, this should work, but I really want to use css3 transitions instead (one of the aims of this website is for me to learn more about the css3 and html5 standards). A similar mechanism using jQuery to handle the callback would be great if it allows me to use separate CSS transitions (which jQuery.animate doesn't)

Answer (score -1):

Create few css classes with css3-transitions and use .addClass/removeClass in success/error/complete callbacks

http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/ — transitions are acceptable despite of initial state, that's why you can use them fully asynchronous.

Answer (score -1):

I found $.Deferred to be the best approach to solving this problem. I won't go too much into how it works but just explain the benefits and solution.

Here is the documentation.
http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/
I found this was a great resource to get started with $.Deferred.
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/async/deferred/

So basically you want to combine CSS3 animations with ajax requests which are both asynchronous. Yet you want to use callbacks so that effect to be synchronous or coordinated, i.e. fade some element out ajax in a new element in its place then fade it in. The advantage of using $.Deferred is that you can coordinate these events in a more "sophisticated?" way. Instead of fade out then do an ajax request then fade in, which is ok but it means you have to wait for your animation to finish before even starting the request. With $.Deferred you can do something like fade out and fire an ajax request and when they are both finished fade in.

Heres a working fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/SB987/1/

I'll comment through the js part below.

```
//Clicking the anchor triggers the loadContent function
$('a').on('click', function(){
    var url     =   $(this).data('url');
    var target  =   $(this).data('target');
    loadContent(url, target);
});

//Slide out the existing element using a css transform
var slideOut = function($el, $target){
    //Create a deffered object
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();
    //Slide our element out (note this has a transition through css) (double note you should use transforms for other browsers
    $el.css({"-webkit-transform":"translateX(100%)"}).on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd', function(e){
       //once the transition ends resolve our deferred object and return $target
       deferred.resolve($target);
    });
    //return the promise from the deferred object
    return deferred.promise();
};

//Add the element returned from our Ajax request and slide it in
var slideIn = function(el, $target){
    var $el = $(el);
    $target.empty().append($el).css({height : "auto"});
    //weird bug, css transition doesn't work when taken out of setTimeout (any ideas?)
    setTimeout(function(){
        $el.removeClass('content2');
    }, 0);
};


//Make an ajax request and returns some html
//Note ajax requests return promises as well as deferred objects, I am just wrapping it here for clarity
var getData = function(url){
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();
    //var htmlData = "asdfasfasdf";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method : "POST",
        data : { 'html': htmlData},
         success: function (returnhtml) {
             //resolve our deferred object and return the response
             deferred.resolve(returnhtml);
         },
         error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
             //you can reject a deferred object and then execute a different callback(s) but i'll let you figure that out
             deferred.reject(thrownError);
         }
    });
    //return the promise from the deferred object
    return deferred.promise();
}


var loadContent = function(url, target){
    $el = $('.content');
    $target = $(target);
    //Run slideOut and getData
    var slidePromise = slideOut($el, $target);
    var dataPromise = getData(url);
    //So because we are returning promises from deferred objects in both of the above functions the following code will only run once those deferred objects have been resolved
    $.when(slidePromise, dataPromise).done(function(slidePromise, dataPromise) {
        //Great the ajax request is finished and our slideOut animation has finished, lets slide in the new content passing it the target element and response content
        slideIn(dataPromise, slidePromise );
    });
};
```